# Login to https site from Windows without specifying domain

Tags: windows, outlook

I have added a network calendar (served by radicale) to Outlook:
[image: screenshot of step one]

Now a Windows security message is raised asking for login credentials.
[image: Windows screen asking for credentials]

However, the domain of the computer is automatically added `computername\user`, while the server expect to recieve `user` only.

How can I login without prepending a `domain` name to the `username`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In username field just write a backslash before your username:

`\username`

You'll see that the domain will remain empty.

Answer (score 1):

Click on `more choices`.
Enter the desired username and password.

Comment: I do not have this button "more options". I have updated the screenshot above

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I misunderstood your problem, but I have to confirm the process you performed:

1. Add an internet calendar(**`.ics`** link) which is served by **radicale** server to Outlook

[image]

2. Outlook prompted you to enter your account's credential(Windows automatically filled the full UPN(computername\user).)

[image]

Right? If some of the above details are different from yours, please provide the related screenshots in your edited post for further troubleshooting(**Please alter any sensitive info**.).

Comment: You have rephrased my question correctly. I have added the screenshots to the original question. Do you also have suggestions for an answer?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Vasco Try adding a ".\" in front of the account name and enter the password. For example: User Name: **.\Administrator** , Password: **Password**.